# How to assign id to the bar chart

Tags: d3.js

How can I assign id base on its name?
the link of the screenshot of the console is down below.
Thanks

[image]

```
serie.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class","bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.Company); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("id",function(d,i){
        return "id"+ d.name;
      })
```

Comment: Do you want to set an id to each bar ? What problem(s) are you encountering? Are you getting any error(s)?

Comment: Sorry I did not write it clear enough. I'm drawing a stacked bar chart. and I have to assign each stacked in each bar a id to have some animation on each of them. I use '.attr("id",function(d,i){
        return "id"+ d.name;
      })' to add the id, but it keeps showing id="idundefined"

Comment: Can you please post the whole code? Are you transforming the data for stacking using d3.layout.stack() ?

Comment: What is the content of d? Tried .data(d)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discourage assigning `id`s to every bar as `id`s need to be unique. Its better to have a class instead. But as requested, I have posted a fiddle below. Hover on the bars to get the `id`. And you also said you need the `id` for animating so I've also added some animations when the chart loads (If that's what you meant by animation).

```js
// Setup svg using Bostock's margin convention

var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 160,
  bottom: 35,
  left: 30
};

var width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

var data = [{
  mystate: "Intuit",
  name: "Asian",
  y0: 53,
  y1: 1824,
  value: "1771"
}, {
  mystate: "Intuit",
  name: "Latino",
  y0: 2707,
  y1: 1231,
  value: "1771"
}, {
  mystate: "Intuit",
  name: "Black_or_African_American",
  y0: 2060,
  y1: 1824,
  value: "1771"
}, {
  mystate: "Intuit",
  name: "Caucasian",
  y0: 355,
  y1: 1024,
  value: "1771"
}];


// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(['y0', 'y1'].map(function(values) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: d.name,
      y: +d[values],
    };
  });
}));


// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width - 10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d, function(d) {
      return d.y0 + d.y;
    });
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];


// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d
  });

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");


svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return height;
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return 0;
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr('id', function(d) {
    return 'id' + d.x;
  })
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    console.log(d3.select(this).attr('id'));
    tooltip.style("display", null);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    tooltip.style("display", "none");
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  }).transition().duration(1000)
  .delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * 300;
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y);
  }).attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0 + d.y);
  });





// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");

tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```css
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

path.domain {
  stroke: none;
}

.y .tick line {
  stroke: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.13/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Now coming back to your code, when you transform the data by using `d3.layout.stack()` there is no property called `name` in your new data (I suppose) and hence your `id`s are `idundefined`